# Is it safe to change BIOS settings with a hibernated Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bios, hibernate, power-management, cpu-cooler

I'd like to know if it is possible to change BIOS settings safely with a hibernated Windows 10 session, particularly with CPU fan speed/power management?

My problem has to do with my system/CPU fan not spinning as much as it should when I awake my system from hibernation. I can restart my system, have CPUID HWMonitor running with a normal readings of 2000 and so RPM, hibernate the system, come back and check all the fan reading are now at 0 RPM, and I can look into my case and see that the fan isn't spinning as hard as it should look when normal. After a while, the readings turn towards a very subpar 200~ RPM. So I haven't gamed in a while because of that.

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/cpu-fan-not-spinning-after-sleep.1334201/
https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/bbu5cy/system_fan_not_spinning_after_sleep/

[HWmonitor readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uudSM.png)

I am aware that properly changing BIOS settings is done with the system fully turned off, but I already had trouble with some crashes wiping my sessions these last few days so I am just feeling really lazy and want to change something and see if it sticks. (I ran DISM, sfc and chkdsk and all before beginning my current session, in case you're curious. I also reset my overclock to more reasonable numbers a while back. Windows power plan is on maximum performance. Maybe an ASUS program, or MSI Afterburner, are not helping matters?). So can any of the BIOS settings that are possibly related to my problems be safely changed?

My specs:

Mobo: ASUS Z390-A Prime
CPU: i7-8700k
GPU: AMD R7 260x
RAM: 16 GB Dual-channel
OS: Windows 10 Pro 21H1

Comment: When you say replace the BIOS, do you mean physically remove the EEPROM/EPLD from the motherboard and plug in a new one? Or do you mean flash the firmware?

Comment: No updates or anything, just the BIOS settings/options.

Answer (score 2):

A hibernated system is written to disk and the computer is essentially OFF.

The issue easily could be that a BIOS update could change power and hibernation settings that reside in BIOS.

So simply put, do not try to update BIOS while the OS is hibernated.

Start it up, get it running normally, and then shut down fully. Now it is safe to update BIOS.

Comment: Even if you do perform a firmware upgrade or change, Windows will likely decide the hibernation state is stale, and which will result in a warm restart state (with respect to Windows.  There is also the fact the system will perform a restart to apply the firmware upgrade and/or change, which will have an effect on the hibernation state of Windows, and would again likely result in a warm restart state with respect to Windows.  Of course I would not attempt to update the firmware of a system without performing a full shutdown before hand.

Comment: Oh I don't mean a BIOS update, just BIOS settings

Comment: Whether changing BIOS settings, or updating BIOS - either one, be sure the system is fully OFF.